# Calculate Weighted Geometric Average with Excel function

Tags: vba, excel, function, formula

I am a beginner with Excel-VBA and I need to create a function to calculate the **geometric weighted average**, given a list of values (`Mi`), and a list of weights (`Wi').

The Excel formula is: `EXP((SUM(Wi*LN(Mi))/(sum(Wi))`

I'm having difficulty with the "Sum" section of the formula. This is what I have done so far:

```
Function GEOWAMC(Wi as Double, Mi as Double) As Double
    Range("A1").Formual="Sum("& Range(Cells(2,1), Cells(2,3)).Address(False,False)&")"
    GEOWAMC=((WorksheetFunction.Sum(Wi*ln(Mi))/(worksheetFunction.sum(Wi)))
End Function
```

Comment: You cannot set another cell's formula from a udf on the worksheet.

Comment: Would that means I need to create two different function?

Comment: **You cannot set another cell's formula from a udf on the worksheet.** so either type the formula into A1 or write a Sub (not a function) that writes the formula into A1. fwiw, it isn't at all clear why you are trying to write the formula into A1.

Comment: Can you please give an example of data this would be used with?  (You have a few issues there but the big one is that your function isn't going to accept more than one cell like it is.)

Comment: The objective is to calculate the Geometric Weighted Average Market Cap of a portfolio. I could have 40 stocks ( as an example) and each of them would represent a certain percentage of my total portfolio. that would be "Wi". In order to calculate this, we also need the current market cap of each stock, which would be "Mi". (If I could I would attached my excel sheet example, I can't find the feature on this blog)

Comment: I think It might actually be easier to do it as a Sub and simply record a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guarantee that you're mot the first person who's needed to calculate this - or *any other math function you can think of* - in Excel.  A search for "weighted geometric mean excel" lead me to an [answer](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/914895-how-to-calculate-weighted-geometric-mean-in-excel.html#post3197806) (likely the same place you got the function).

It's good to see that you attempted to solve this yourself, however it's not the "Sum" section that's preventing your function from working.

---

### Debugging Your VBA Function:

I'm afraid there are ***a number*** of things wrong with your code.  That number is ***"Nine"***.

- Most importantly, you transposed your formulas criteria in your explanation.
  **The parameter that starts with the `W` is the *Weight***, and the *other* parameter is the *Value*.
- If you want to use parameters with more than 1 cell, you use **`Range`** (not `Double`).
- **You cannot assign a value directly to a cell** (or change a cell in *any* other way) from within a function.  Functions *return* values to the cell from which it was called.
- **`Address(False, False)`** isn't going to accomplish anything productive in this case.
  (You need better understanding of the purpose of relative vs. absolute references.)
- Instead of using: `Range(Cells(2,1), Cells(2,3)).Address(False,False)`
  ...you could use **`A2:C2`** because they mean *exactly* the same thing (and always will).
- Therefore, all this:
  `Range("A1").Formual="Sum("& Range(Cells(2,1), Cells(2,3)).Address(False,False)&")`
  ...can be shortened to: **`[A1]=[A2]+[B2]+[C2]`**
  ...because they are mean *exactly* the same thing (and always will).
- You're using *worksheet functions* in VBA, which is fine in *some* cases
  ...but the function is **`Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum`**.
- The *natural logarithm* function `LN` accepts only **one** value when used one it's own
  ...not a "list" (or range of cells)
- You should use **`Option Explicit`** at the top of each module, especially when *learning* or *troubleshooting*; it would have helped you catch at least a couple of these mistakes.
- Also you have a couple unnecessary sets of parentheses, but *that's* not a big deal.

So, you *could* work on fixing all of that, *or better yet*, you could **use it as a worksheet function** and save yourself (or someone else) a lot of work *for no reason*.

---

### Using the Worksheet Function

**Syntax:**

> **`=EXP(SUMPRODUCT(`** *`WeightRange`* **`,LN(`** *`ValueRange`* **`))/SUM(`** *`WeightRange`* **`))`**
>
> - note that **the same** `*WeightRange*` is entered twice.
> - the `*WeightRange*` and `*ValueRange*` **must both be the same size**.

**Example:**

> *If:*
>    - cells `A1 to A5` contains your values, *and,*
>    - cells `B1 to B5` contain the weights for the values, *and,*
>    - you wanted the *Weighted Geometric Mean* in cell `C1`

...then in `C1` you would enter:

```
=EXP(SUMPRODUCT(B1:B5,LN(A1:A5))/SUM(B1:B5))
```

I suspect that this will suffice as a solution, now that we've walked through it, but if you have an *actual* *reason* that you need this calculation to take place within a VBA Function then by all means let me know and me will figure it out.  :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was extremely useful!